# Не удаляется связная сущность

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Есть две сущности, между ними есть отношение ManyToOne

```
  public class Cinema
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FilmRoom>? FilmRooms { get; set; }
  }

  public class FilmRoom
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CinemaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Cinema Cinema { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Session>? Sessions { get; set; }
  }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cinema>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            entity.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(c => c.Description).HasMaxLength(2048).IsRequired(false);
            entity
              .HasMany(f => f.FilmRooms)
              .WithOne(c => c.Cinema)
              .HasForeignKey(c => c.CinemaId);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FilmRoom>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(f => f.Id);
            entity.HasAlternateKey(f => new {f.Name, f.CinemaId});
            entity.Property(f=> f.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        });
  }
```

В коде я выбираю нужный кинотеатр и добавляю или удаляю кинозалы, при добавлении все сохраняется и нормально работает, но удаление не работает

```
   var db = new MHDataBase();//контекст бд
   var cinema = db.Cinemas.First();
   // тут пользователь может добавлять или удалять залы
   Cinema.FilmRooms = filmRooms;// присваиваю лист залов к кинотеатру
   db.Cinemas.Update(Cinema);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: А `filmRooms` вообще взялся из `Cinema.FilmRooms`?

Comment: да, при открытии окна и `Cinema` берутся `FilmRooms`

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF Core. / `virtual` - используется ленивая загрузка. Сейчас это считается моветоном. / Как именно происходит удаление? Покажите код.